# Having trouble matching users input to a .json file, keep getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: myExp is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, json

I keep getting an error when I try to match users input data to a .json file.  Here is my .js:

```
$.getJSON('rote.json', function(data){
    var random = data.eats[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.eats.length)];
    var title = random[0].cat;
    var titleLength = random[0].cat.length;

    $("h2").html(title);

    var output = '';

    $.each(random, function(key,val){
        var snippedFieldLength = random.length - 1;
        output += '<input type="search" name="search" class="search" placeholder="write your tag here" /><br><br>';

    });

    $('.fields').html(output);


    $('.search').keyup(function(){
        var searchField = $('.search:eq(1)').val();
        var myExp = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
        console.log(myExp);


        var output2 = '';
        $.each(random, function(key,val){
            console.dir(val);
            if (val.search(myExp) != -1) {
                output2 += 'hello';
            }
        });
        $('#update').html(output2);
    });
});
```

Here is my .json file:

```
{"eats":
  [
    [
      {"cat":"drinks"},
      "soda",
      "milk"
    ],
    [
      {"cat":"food"},
      "burgers",
      "fries",      
      "pizza"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to match data I'm getting from a .json file to text inserted into html input fields generated using a loop. All of this is done with .json and jquery.  I have no trouble randomly selecting items from my json category 'eats' and I have no trouble spontaneously creating fields that conform the the length of the categories (minus 1, since the 'cat' items should be excluded), but my problem is that I can't seem to get the regular expression to match the text the user will enter to the .json file.  Does anybody have any ideas?  I keep getting a "Uncaught ReferenceError: myExp is not defined" error.

Comment: That is definitely true, but even when I put it into the correct scope, the error remains.  Thank you for your help though.

Comment: I get a different error: `TypeError: undefined is not a function` from the line `val.search(myExp)`. This is because `val` is the object `{cat: "drink"}`, and this object doesn't have a `search` method.

Comment: @Easy What do you mean? The scope of `myExp` is the `.search` keyup handler. It's being used in a function nested inside that function, so it's in scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error I get when I run your code is that `undefined is not a function`. When you loop over `random`, the first value is the object `{ cat: "categoryname" }`, and when you call `val.search(myExp)` it gets an error because that object doesn't have a `.search` method. The solution is to test whether the element is a string before trying to match it. Or you could use `$.each(random.slice(1), function() { ...})` to skip over the first element.

```js
function processJson(data){
    var random = data.eats[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.eats.length)];
    var title = random[0].cat;
    var titleLength = random[0].cat.length;

    $("h2").html(title);

    var output = '';

    $.each(random, function(key,val){
        var snippedFieldLength = random.length - 1;
        output += '<input type="search" name="search" class="search" placeholder="write your tag here" /><br><br>';

    });

    $('.fields').html(output);


    $('.search').keyup(function(){
        var searchField = $('.search:eq(1)').val();
        var myExp = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
        console.log(myExp);


        var output2 = '';
        $.each(random, function(key,val){
            console.dir(val);
            if (typeof val == "string" && val.search(myExp) != -1) {
                output2 += 'hello';
            }
        });
        $('#update').html(output2);
    });
}

var myjson = 
{"eats":
  [
    [
      {"cat":"drinks"},
      "soda",
      "milk"
    ],
    [
      {"cat":"food"},
      "burgers",
      "fries",      
      "pizza"
    ]
  ]
};

processJson(myjson);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2></h2>

Fields:
<div class="fields"></div>
Update:
<div id="update"></div>
```

The best solution would be to redesign your data structure. Arrays should be used for uniform data, objects should be used for heterogeneous data. So it's inappropriate to have the object in the same array as the strings. This is how I suggest you do it:

```
[
    { cat: "drinks",
      members: [
        "soda",
        "milk"
        ]
    },
    { cat: "food",
      members: [
          "burgers",
          "fries",      
          "pizza"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you.  I suspected my code was whacked out.  I really appreciate your help.